# (Nginx Windows) nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "serversupstream"

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I got this code while executing `nginx`:

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "serversupstream" in C:\nginx-1.17.9/conf/nginx.conf:15
```

This is my nginx.conf:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;
    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    # List of application 
    serversupstream portal_server {
      server 127.0.0.1:9510;
    }
    upstream portal_web_server {
      server 127.0.0.1:8085;
    }
    server {
      listen       8001;
      server_name  localhost;
      location /api {
          proxy_pass <http://portal_server;>
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_redirect     off;
          proxy_set_header Host               $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
      }
      location /dte {
          proxy_pass <http://portal_web_server;>
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_redirect     off;
          proxy_set_header Host               $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
      }
      location /simulacion {
          proxy_pass <http://portal_web_server;>
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_redirect     off;
          proxy_set_header Host               $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
      }
    }
    include servers/*;
}
```

I don't know that error message, what it is?

EDIT:

According to http://nginx.org/en/docs/dirindex.htm there is no `serversupstream` I don't understand, I'm just using a nginx.conf that many other guys in the team are using, but they are on mac and/or linux, I'm the only one in Windows.

So, I change `serversupstream` to `upstream` and there it triggers another error, it's complaining about the prefix for:

```
proxy_pass <http://portal_web_server;>
```

So I change removed those `<>` and there I tried again, now nginx doesn't show anything in the console... just this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

change encoding of the configfile to  Utf8.
Don't use built'in Notepad.exe to  Save as to Uft8, it will save as Utf8 BOM.
Use Notepad++ or other editor.